# How to I add vis.js to Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How do I install and use the Vis.js in Vue.js:

I have tried following the guidance below but it states `Viz is not a constructor`

https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/wiki/Usage

Comment: Have you installed the NPM package and imported it, or are you using a script tag to import it?

Comment: I have installed it via NPM and then imported it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Viz from 'viz.js';
import workerURL from 'file-loader!viz.js/full.render.js';
var viz = new Viz({ workerURL });

viz.renderSVGElement('digraph { a -> b; }')
.then(function (element) {
  document.body.appendChild(element);
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

These packages might help, their aim is to adopt Vis to Vue:

1. https://github.com/r3code/vue-vis-network
2. https://github.com/alexcode/vue2vis